# No gulp file found (windows)

Tags: gulp

have a problem with gulp. I've been using gulp for 3 months. And for the first time a have an issue like this:

When I try to run gulp, command line shows: no gulp file found. I use node, and I got project from my friend to fix code. Thank, U!

Answer (score 0):

`gulp` is telling you that it doesn't have a gulpfile with instructions for it to follow. Please make sure you were in correct directory that contains **gulpfile.js**. It will be better if you could show your project structure here.